# "Raspberry Pi Pico Support Requires Valid Python 3.5+ SDK"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Error: "Raspberry Pi Pico Support Requires Valid Python 3.5+ SDK"

So I recently installed MicroPython for my raspeberry pi pico and followed all direction to get it ready. I chose pycharm as my editor and when getting ready to code I am greeated with this error message. [image: Attemping To Run Code]

I have tried everything and it also seems like there is a problem with the micro python code itself like its running an older verions of pyhton.[image: When Coding]

I have python version 3.10.2 which should be supported.

I have tried getting a different version of python and also figuring why its saying the micropython exstion code it unsupported for pyhton2. [image: MicroPython Extenstion Code Error(Was not tinkered with)]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and for me the issue in the end was that I had not set/created a interpreter for the project. Once I added that it worked for me.